# Submit an array of selected files

Tags: angular

```
public upload(images: FileList) {
  const params = new FormData();

  params.append('images', images);

  return this.http.post(`url`, params)
}
```

`console.log(images)` i get a `fileList` with attached files.

How can I send to the server as an array?

Answer (score 0):

To send the FileList as an array to the server using Angular, you can convert it to an array and send it as part of the request payload. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
public upload(images: FileList) {
   const params = new FormData();

   const imagesArray = Array.from(images); // Convert FileList to an array

   imagesArray.forEach((image, index) => {
       params.append(`images[${index}]`, image); // Append each file to the FormData with an indexed key
     });

     return this.http.post('url', params);
   }
```

Comment: After ```post``` i see in payload ```images[0]:binary, images[1]:binary```. But i need like ```images[]: file1, fil2, etc``` is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to send the files as an array in the payload instead of using indexed keys

Comment: What should be changed in your code in order to achieve this goal?